# Stuck partition on Mac.

Tags: partitioning, mac, delete

After I used rEFIt to put Linux on my mac, it tried installing windows, but I stopped it. The partition doesn't show up in terminal or disk utility. It's like a 'ghost' partition and it shows up when I boot holding ALT. I can't use it because it says no operating system found. How do I delete this?

Comment: This question may be a better fit for [Super User](http://www.superuser.com) because it isn't really a question about Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

You can erase a  partition using Disk Utility. Boot to Mac OS X, start up Disk Utility, select your harddrive, click Partitioning, click the partition and then click the - . If you want, you can now extend other partitions to use the freed up space by dragging their handles. Then click Apply and you are done.